# Wrapping text inside framebox

Tags: line-breaking, framed

I would like to wrap the text inside a `\framebox`, such that it continues on the next line instead of running out of the margins.

A minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\begin{document}

\framebox{\textit{If this script fails, you can try the following: 
  lower the degree (d), decrease the number of simplices, increase 
 the order of continuity (if possible) or increase the number of 
 datapoints in the listed simplices}}.

\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set the contents of the `\framebox` in a `\parbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\framebox{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\itshape%
  If this script fails, you can try the following: lower the degree~(d), 
  decrease the number of simplices, increase the order of continuity (if possible) 
  or increase the number of datapoints in the listed simplices.}}

\end{document}
```

The calculations (using `\dimexpr`) ensures that the width of the box *excludes* the gap between the contents and the frame (2 gaps of `\fboxsep` and 2 widths of `\fboxrule` on either side). Also, since you're probably not interested in a paragraph indent *outside* this block, I've used `\noindent`.

Note that this block is not breakable across the page boundary.

Comment: Great, exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!